# NullReferenceException When Resolving SpriteBatch with Ninject

Tags: ninject, monogame

I have a very, very basic MonoGame game (almost just a new project, with just a single image drawn on screen).

In my `Game` class, I created an instance of `StandardKernel`. In `LoadContent`, I bind it to my `SpriteBatch`:

```
protected override void LoadContent ()
{
    // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
    this.SpriteBatch = new SpriteBatch (GraphicsDevice);

    // Setup DI bindings
    this.Kernel.Bind<SpriteBatch>().ToConstant<SpriteBatch>(this.spriteBatch);

    //TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
}
```

(The debugger hits this line.) Later, I try to consume it:

```
protected void LoadSpritesLater() {
  var spriteBatch = Game.Instance.Kernel.Get<SpriteBatch>();
}
```

For some reason, this line always throws a `NullReferenceException`. I've verified that `Game.Instance.Kernel` returns me a `StandardKernel` instance, that I expect.

Oddly, if I replace the `Bind` call with a setter (eg. `this.SpriteBatch = spriteBatch)`, I can fetch it in `LoadSpritesLater` and use it without issue.

I checked the Ninject source code and docs to see if the instance is created through Ninject itself (it seems like it isn't). I don't see why this isn't working.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain the two kernels are the same object, and not just two different instances of StandardKernel? If yes, try instead of binding to a constant, try binding to a method that returns the spritebatch.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard I get the same exception. I verified they're the same kernel by comparing the hash codes, and by calling `GetBindings(typeof(SpriteBatch))` on both instances in the debugger. The bindings are there.

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard strangely enough, this only occurs on the very first call to `Get<SpriteBatch>()`. After that, it works fine.